# Javascript function undefined return

Tags: javascript, return, undefined

```
<script>
    var tarih = tarih();
    alert(tarih);
    function tarih() {   
       var s=emrah;
       return(s);
    }
</script>
```

Bu fonksion neden undefined dönüyor ?

Why "undefined" returns?

Comment: because emrah is undefined, so s = emrah makes s undefined, and return s makes the return undefined ... also `var tarih = tarih();` will assign tarih with the return value, and then the function tarih will no longer exist

Comment: It doesn't, the code produces a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it returns `undefined`, is because of the assigment

```
var s = emrah
```

is confusing JS. So, it looks for a var name `emrah` and doesn't find it. That is the reason, you get `undefined`. Plus, if you are looking at your console, it would already have given you an error message, that

```
emrah is not defined
```

You might want to try: (If that's what you wanted)

```
var s = 'emrah'
```

Comment: That's incorrect. JavaScript does not create a global variable when you try to *read* an undeclared variable. It throws an error.

Comment: @FelixKling, it throws an error if you have used  'use strict', otherwise it creates it.

Comment: haha, I do believe you :). Will take that, I was under the impression, it does. Thanks for that.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling the method before its defined.

Change the code to something like this.

```js
<script>
    function tarih() {   
       var s='emrah';
       return(s);
    }
    var tarih = tarih();
    alert(tarih);
</script>
```

Comment: Function declarations are hoisted.